# How do I display a TextView when a ListView is empty?

Tags: android, listview, view, android-listfragment, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a ListFragment that returns a ListView. If there are no items in the list, I'd like to display an alternative TextView instead. Supposedly you can add a *TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"* element within the XML.

But...

Adding FrameLayout containing *both* the ListView and the TextView predictably gives me *"FrameLayout cannot be cast to ListView"*.

I can't *just* add a TextView element either. *"The markup in the document following the root element must be wellformed."*

And I can't switch to *View* instead of *ListView* because, well, it would no longer be a list.

...how am I supposed to do this?

Code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Project> ( getActivity (), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    arrayList = ProjectManager.getProjectList ( getActivity () );
    for ( Project p : arrayList ) {
        if ( p.getStatus () == Project.ONGOING ) {
            adapter.add ( p );
        }
    }

    ListView listView = ( ListView ) inflater.inflate ( R.layout.list, container, false );
    listView.setAdapter ( adapter );

    return listView;
}
```

XML:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a ListFragment that returns a ListView. If there are no items in the list, I'd like to display an alternative TextView instead. Supposedly you can add a TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" element within the XML.

You can.

> Adding FrameLayout containing both the ListView and the TextView predictably gives me "FrameLayout cannot be cast to ListView".

That's because of the bug in your code, where you assume that the results of `inflate()` is a `ListView`. Change that to use `findViewById()` to *find* the `ListView` in the inflated layout.

Comment: I tried the following, but that gives me "the specified child already has a parent". Code: "ListView listView = ( ListView ) inflater.inflate ( R.layout.list_projects_ongoing, container, false ).findViewById ( R.id.listView );"

Comment: @CaptainHindsight: That line does not give you that error. Something else might, but not that line. Also, you need to return the results of `inflate()` from `onCreateView()`, and in your case, you cannot be, as you are throwing out the `inflate()` results.

Answer (score 0):

add a TextView with id empty:

```
<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/emptyt_message" />
```

to the same layout

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)

For this to be useful, your fragment should consist of a container (i.e. `FrameLayout`) containing both the `ListView` and a `TextView` with your empty message.

When inflating your layout, specify the view id of the text view. Set this text view's initial visibility to `INVISIBLE`. The text view's visibility is updated automatically according to the number of elements within your adapter.